# Unable to set colors in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, colors, vbo

I have an OpenGL scene, made as VBO and IBO.
My VBO is a serie of 3 floats: x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z...
In addition to that, I have a color array made of series of 3 floats: r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b...

My goal is that the first vertice (x=vertice[0], y=vertice[1], z=vertice[2]) is linked to the first color (r=color[0], g=color[1], b=color[2]).
I am however unable to display the colors with the code below:

```
    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexVBOID);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*nbVertex*3, glVertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexVBOID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int)*nbVBOInd, VBOInd, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0,0);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, glColors);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexVBOID);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, nbVBOInd, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Is there an issue in the code above, or in the way my array is set up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this sequence a try:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBOID);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, glColors);
```

Also, look at the [docs for `glBindBuffer()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindBuffer.xml):

> Buffer object names are unsigned integers. The value zero is reserved,
>   but there is no default buffer object for each buffer object target.
>   Instead, **`buffer` set to zero effectively unbinds any buffer object
>   previously bound, and restores client memory usage for that buffer
>   object target**.